# PCI-E / Linux : How to capture TLP packet?

Tags: pci

Is it possible that linux software capture TLP packet of PCI-E?

I want to know debugging pci-e card.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe so -- from a software viewpoint, PCI-E is quite well disguised to look like (fast) PCI.

As far as I know, nearly the only reasonable way to do this is with specialized hardware -- specifically a logic analyzer with a PCI-E bus probe. I've used an Agilent analyzer with a [FuturePlus probe](http://www.futureplus.com/PCI-Express-Aligent-LA-Support/summary.html), and can recommend the combination with only a couple reservations: first, it's not cheap. Second, it can be a bit of a jump for somebody accustomed purely to software.

Comment: So you can’t go around the controller logic in the circuit and reroute the packets themselves to RAM?

Comment: @JackFrye: No--at least not any way of which I'm aware.

Comment: @JackFrye since PCI bus is accessed via DMA, the application that uses the PCI devices will write data direclty to RAM that is assigned to the device, but microprocessors provide debugging interrupts which can trigger a breakpoint upon change in memory. you would need to set the breakpoint when the PCI packet is ready to travel, but not yet sent, and copy it, then continue the app that was interrupted. This obviously will work for devices that work in user space only, but for kernel mode you can use same strategy. This is theory, not sure if it works in practice.

Comment: @Nulik: a debug break would only let you see the raw data that would go into the body of the TLP packet. At least on any PCIe interface of which I'm aware, the TLP packet itself never goes into the host memory.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to debug the actual protocol items, which are called Transaction Layer Packets (TLPs) and Data Link Layer Packets (DLLPs) is to use a hardware PCI Express Protocol Analyzers. Very few are sold so the prices are high. Lots of engineering goes into capturing data at gigabit speeds and presenting it in an easy to decipher form. LeCroy's cheapest unit starts from $16,000. The lowest priced PCI Express Protocol Analyzer on the market is from ITIC ($7,995). This includes the protocol analyzer, a x4 lane slot probe, cables and software.

http://www.internationaltestinstruments.com/products/100-itic-2500a-x4-25-gbps-pci-express-protocol-analyzer.aspx

Comment: Now down to $5000, apparently, and looks great, but note that it's only for PCIe 1.1 (2.5G). But you can probably use it to debug modern cards by bringing the link speed down. I'm currently using a (LeCroy) Gen2 analyser on a Gen3 card and it works fine once you've configured the link to run slower.